# Send a Flat file attachment in the workflow in Informatica Developer

Tags: bioinformatics, informatica

In a mapping we use delimited flat file having 3 columns.The column separated through comma. But i have a requirement  that in between the column there is a column having 2 comma.So how should I process the column in the mapping?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example?

Answer (score 1):

You should have information quoted with `""` so whatever is within `"` is skiped. this way you could differentiate between comma of a piece of information or as a column separator.
We don't know what have you tried, but count the number of commas for each line and separate accordingly (if possible).